# How to increase pool size in MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: miktex, memory

I'm using **MiKTex 2.9.4196** with **TeXnicCenter 2.0 beta** on Windows 7.
As I have to compile very large tikzpictures I use **tikz externalize**. Nevertheless some tikzpicture still produce an error.

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=3147270].
```

I already did increase the main memory, but I couldn't find out how to change the pool-size.

Comment: Related Question: [Compiling a 870 mb latex file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67464/compiling-a-870-mb-latex-file).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the command line option:

```
pdflatex --pool-size=5000000 ....
```

You can also change the pool size e.g. for pdflatex permanantly:
Run on the command line

```
initexmf --edit-config-file pdflatex
```

This will open a local pdflatex.ini in the editor. Add

```
pool_size=4250000
```

Then save the file.

It shouldn't be necessary to rebuild the format for this value, but for other parameters it is sometimes needed.

You can find the default values in the manual in Chapter 10. TEXMF Run-Time Parameters.

Comment: To rebuilt the file, it seems you have to type `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`.