# Overleaf cache not working properly with `\tikzexternalize` and `\include.`

Tags: include, tikz-external

I can confirm that some figures go missing or shows up in the wrong place in Overleaf when combining `\include` and `\tikzexternalize`.

I also tried the suggestion of @usr1234567 in [How to externalize TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482557/how-to-externalize-tikz-pictures) but this has two issues:

1. the file is created but cannot be included (it does not exist)
2. if I upload the pdf, it does not display properly in Overleaf

Any suggestions?

Note:  It is very difficult for me to compile a MWE of this specific issue.

Comment: Overleaf has a guide to externalize, it has some particularities: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz,_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures,_so_I'm_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F

Comment: @LuisTurcio I'm not sure my issue is related to the actual question, but in the overleaf docs you link, there is some cryptic comment: `On Overleaf v2, these files must be prefixed with output, instead of the filename of your .tex.` I managed to get it working by calling `\tikzexternalize` with `\tikzexternalize[prefix=img/tikz/cache/,figure name=output]` (the `prefix` is of course arbitrary, `figure name=output` is the important piece.

Comment: Your issue took so many time to be solved. As you said this overleaf doc is not the best guide. You should post your answer, so it can be helpful for others.