# \tikzexternalize together with drawing on an image with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I am following [this very good answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/180429) that explains how to draw on an image with TikZ. Now I tried to implement this new tikz picture I got with Tikz library `external` but I get the  error

> Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape
> -halt-on-e rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/myTikzFileName" did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/myTikzFileName' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).

I have been working for the last time on a project with ~20 figures, all made with tikz and pgfplots, and the externalization commands worked perfect, up until now when I inserted a png file into tikz.

The graphics I want to insert into my document is the file `myGraphics.tikz`,

```
% myGraphics.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some-image.png}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

implemented with the `tikzscale` package:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}
%% To reduce compilation time
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Lorem Ipsum}{dolor sit amet}
Some text
\begin{figure}
\tikzsetnextfilename{myExternalTikzFile}
\includegraphics[height=100pt]{myGraphics}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I do get a non empty `md5` file, but nothing more.

Do anyone know how to fix this?

(`some-image.png` is [this image](https://i.ibb.co/2cbzYvR/some-image.png))

Comment: works fine for me on a current texlive. Are you sure that you tried with this example? The error message indicates a subfolder, but your prefix has no slash.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You are right, I changed the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I see two possible problems in creating your output file:

- the use of `\includegraphics` to invoke the `.tikz` file; it should rather be something like `\input` (see @sheß [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482557/how-to-externalize-tikz-pictures))
- maybe you don't use `--shell-escape` option when running the document; you need something like `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape main.tex`.

I insert the code below, but the important parts of it are borrowed from sheß's answer.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikzscale}

%% To reduce compilation time
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz]
\newcommand{\inputtikz}[1]{\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}\input{#1.tikz}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \centering
  \inputtikz{myGraphics}
  \caption{Boletus nubes}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What about image size specification? can I define it using `\input{___.tikz}` ?

Comment: You can introduce a variable, something like `\newcommand{myWidth}{0.5}` in the `main.tex` and use it in `myGraphics.tikz` in `\includegraphics[width=\myWidth\textwidth]{mushrooms.png}`.  But it is not very clear for me how it really works: if the value is changed, there is no effect unless I delete manually the file tikzmyGraphics.pdf that was previously created.  At least this is how it works for me.