# pgfplots 3d: un-render overwritten graph

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

Is there a way to tell pgfplots not to render the parts of a 3d graph that are overwritten?

Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat       = newest,
    width        = 10cm,    % width
    height       =  7cm,    % height
    samples      = 20,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that yields:
[image: Generated pdf]

it is possible to see that everything that is overwritten is rendered, slowing down the compilation process, is there any way to optimise this?

---

#### Update 2

Opened an issue with problems related to the implementation of `external` library [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631104/tikzlibrary-external-not-outputting-usable-file)

Comment: If you don't modify the figures that much compared to the rest of the document, you may want to [externalize your Tikz figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482557/how-to-externalize-tikz-pictures/482560).