# tikzlibrary: external not outputting usable file

Tags: pgfplots, errors, tikz-external, compilation-error, external

#### Hello there

Currently trying to implement the external library but cant seem to make it work

```
\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% % Uncommenting generates error
% \usetikzlibrary{external}
% % External lib
% \tikzexternalize % turn externalization on/off
% \tikzsetfigurename{./figures/figure_\arabic{part}.} % set names

\pgfplotsset{
    compat       = newest,
    width        = 10cm,    % width
    height       =  7cm,    % height
    samples      = 10,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting `external` library code generates the following error:

```
Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./figures/figure_0.1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{"stack q"}\input{"stack q"}"' did NOT result in a usable output file './figures/figure_0.1' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in './figures/figure_0.1.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

#### Notes:

- `./figures/figure_0.1.log` was never written, it might seem that there is problem with writing some file, but it isnt the case as files with `.md5` have been created.
- Compilation call is: `lualatex --synctex=1 --shell-escape --output-dir=.build --interaction=nonstopmode --file-line-error %DOC%`

List of `.build` directory files:
[image]

---

#### Update 1

Changes:

- Fix directory to include `.build/`
- Added `tikzset` `external/system call` command

```
\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% uncommenting generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% External lib
\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple},
    prefix=./.build/figures/
] % turn externalization on/off
\tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set names

% Using tikzset returns error
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        --halt-on-error
        --shell-escape
        --interaction=batchmode
        --jobname "\image" "\texsource"
    }
}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}

% \tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set names

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Notes:

- Now its possible to see the `.log` generated files. they all disclaim the same message

```
...
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.13 \tikzsetfigurename
                     {figure_\arabic{part}.} % set names
...
```

Displacing `\tikzsetfigurename` to after `\begin{document}` has no effect.

- removing `--output-directory` option from compilation call and replacing `external` related commands with:

```
% uncommenting generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% External lib
\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple},
    prefix=./figures/
] % turn externalization on/off
\tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set figure names

% Using tikzset returns error
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        --halt-on-error
        --shell-escape
        --interaction=batchmode
        --jobname "\image" "\texsource"
    }
}
```

Still generates the same error as before.

- [`.zip` file for inspection](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1On60L1IgXnSTfJ4jEfMC27IFvFOYb7iV/view?usp=sharing)

---

#### Conclusion

Turns out the problem is that the main file has spaces in the name, creating a new question to address this issue [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/631122/tikzlibrary-external-file-names-with-spaces-issue).

Here is the current working MWE renamed to `stackq.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% uncommenting generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% External lib
\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple},
    prefix=./.build/figures/
] % turn externalization on/off
\tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set figure names

% Using tikzset generates error
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        --halt-on-error
        --shell-escape
        --interaction=batchmode
        --jobname "\image" "\texsource"
    }
}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}

% \tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set figure names

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't make sense to use the external library in the standalone class. What do you to gain from it?

Comment: its not intended to use with `standalone` class, its just an example, the class is used just to simplify the MWE

Comment: standalone doesn't simplify! That is a very complex class with lots of internal low-level tricks. Use article for a real MWE.

Comment: Alright then, having it as an `article` is better for everyone. Note here that the error persists after changing to the `article` class.

Comment: i have no problems with your example in a current texlive. Did you activate --shell-escape? And do you use some redirection like --output-directory which could confuse the compilation?

Comment: i do both, shell escape is activated (will add the compilation call to the question as a note), and the `--output-directory` is set'd to `.build/` which is the one displayed in the question.

Comment: well try if it works if you don't use --output-directory.

Comment: It doesn't, but i see that `figure_0.0.log` can now be written, updating that in the question

Comment: you should update the example so that it shows what you are actually using. Currently the externalizing is commented.

Comment: the `externalize` related commands were commented cause they aren't working, the procedure i'm using is the (now updated) current one (without commenting out).

Comment: you still have  a prefix pointing to build. When I remove that (or use only `prefix= figures/` everything works fine.

Comment: Even tho it isn't in the question, the removal of `output-directory` still generates an error, going to add a note on that

Comment: I meant the `prefix=./.build/figures/` key, it quite probably points now to an not existing directory.

Comment: I took that in consideration, still generates an error. You can see exactly how it's changed with the new note in the question.

Comment: then package the testfile and the figures folder with all the logs in a zip and put them somewhere for inspection.

Comment: Which configuration they shaw be set? with or without using `--output-directory` as `.build/`

Comment: make it as simple as possible. The best would be to remove the prefix and to have everything in one folder.

Comment: Rename your main file `stackq.tex` (without spaces!)

Comment: It works! so the problem is the spaces in the file name, how to solve that?

Comment: Do not use spaces. :-)

Comment: too much trouble, there must be a way for it. with `subfiles` i solved by creating a command `\mainfile` with the file name (using spaces), there must be something similar with `externalise`

Comment: Please ask another question on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will share my setup. (windows, TeXstudio, MiKTeX)

(0) No spaces in the filename! Use `stackq.tex`

(1)  Using `lualatex.exe -synctex=1  -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape  %.tex`

(2) `TestExternalize.tex` in the working directory `EXTERNALIZE` with a subdirectory `FIGURES`

[image: c]

```
%%% File TestExternalize.tex

\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% % Uncommenting does not generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize[% added <<<<<<<<<<<
up to date check={simple},
prefix=./FIGURES/]% Folder needs to be created before compiling

\tikzset{external/system call={% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        -halt-on-error -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode
        -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}


\pgfplotsset{
    compat       = newest,
    width        = 10cm,    % width
    height       =  7cm,    % height
    samples      = 10,
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis]
            
            \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
            ]{
                x^2-y^2
            };
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[hide axis]
            
            \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
            ]
            (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
            );
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(3) Directory structure after compiling.

[image: A]

(4) Output `TestExternalize.pdf`

[image: b]

(5) When compiling a second time (faster) the following messages appear

```
===== Image './FIGURES/TestExternalize-figure0' is up-to-date. ======
===== Image './FIGURES/TestExternalize-figure1' is up-to-date. ======
```

Comment: +1: Out of curiosity, did you ever implemented a functionality that names the external files according to the figure caption in the document? For example "Figure3-2.pdf".

Comment: That would actually be great, using this i could instead of modifying the figure filenames to include `part` and other divisions i could set it as it is in the document, unfortunately i dont know how to do that

Comment: @DJ9  Did you try my procedure in your system? It works and answer your question?

Comment: Sorry @Simon, the compilation still ends failing.
Ive tried not using the `output-directory` option in the procedure as well, still fails.

Comment: @ Dr. Manuel Kuehner In a book I used `\tikzsetnextfilename{..}` to set the filename, like  `\tikzsetnextfilename{Chap05/FIGURES/Ch05fig03}
 \begin{figure}
  \input{Chap05/Ch05-modelSgalaxies.tikz}
  \caption{Regression model of S galaxies.}
  \label{fig:modelSgalaxies}
 \end{figure}`.