# tikzlibrary: external file names with spaces issue

Tags: tikz-external, compilation-error, jobname, externalize

#### Hello there

Currently trying to implement `tikz`'s `external` library to a file named `stack q.tex`

MWE:

```
\newcommand\subfilename{"./stack q.tex"}
\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% uncommenting generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% External lib
\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple},
    prefix=./.build/figures/
] % turn externalization on/off
\tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set figure names

% Using tikzset generates error
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        --halt-on-error
        --shell-escape
        --interaction=batchmode
        --jobname "\image" \subfilename
    }
}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}

% \tikzsetfigurename{figure_\arabic{part}.} % set figure names

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The compilation never completes, its stuck in the creation of `figure_0.0.aux` with the following message being display in the terminal:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021) 
 system commands enabled.
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Comment: Why  it is important to you to use spaces in filenames? Why not hyphen instead?

Comment: I echo Simon's comment. You will have problems with different (older) software (not just LaTeX and friends) when you try to use spaces in filenames. Just use `_` or `-`.

Comment: When you have many files its handy to use a name scheme ex. `[group] - [kind] [index].[ext]`, having `_` instead of spaces eliminates the possibility to search trough many files, which is troublesome.

Comment: try to quote the name `--jobname "\image" "\subfilename"` . But Simon is right: you can spent a lot time debugging problems with unquoted or wrongly quoted file names if they contain spaces. I never use them (which is why I had no problems with your example in your last question ...). I don't understand your remark about searching. Wildcards don't require spaces.

Comment: Sorry Ulrike, adding the quotes does not work, nor any combination of quotes (with/without) in the `\newcommand\subfilename{"*.tex"}` and `--jobname "\image" "\subfilename"`

Comment: Without spaces the whole file name is treated as a single word, confusing search engines whenever you want to search based on keywords inside file names, even tho latex generated pdfs can have custom keywords, thanks to `hyperref`, other files such as excel, scripts and codes don't, and having different name schemes would be a real mess, as many interact with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Even when space is not a prohibited character in filenames, the experience of several commenters recommends staying on the safe side and avoiding using it to save debugging time. You experienced it firsthand in your last question.

Coming back to your question, since you already have a naming scheme for filenames and would like to easily locate a figure generated by externalize,  use `\tikzsetnextfilename{<my-naming-scheme>}` before the tikz image (without spaces!) to set the filename of the figure created.

In the next example, with two sections, `\tikzsetnextfilename{FIG_section_\thesection_paraboloid}` was used  for the first and `\tikzsetnextfilename{FIG_section_\thesection_convex}` for the second.

After compiling (`stackq.tex`) the output is

[image: f]

```
%%  file stackq.tex

\documentclass{article}

% pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% uncommenting generates error
\usetikzlibrary{external}
% External lib
\tikzexternalize[
    up to date check={simple},
    prefix=./figures/
] % turn externalization on/off

% Using tikzset generates error
\tikzset{%
    external/system call={%
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
        --halt-on-error
        --shell-escape
        --interaction=batchmode
        --jobname "\image" "\texsource"        
    }
}


\pgfplotsset{
    compat  = newest,
    width   = 10cm,    % width
    height  =  7cm,    % height
    samples = 10,
}

\begin{document}
    
\section{First} 
    
\tikzsetnextfilename{FIG_section_\thesection_paraboloid}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            domain   = -1:1,
            domain y = -1:1,
        ]{
            x^2-y^2
        };
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\section{Second}

\tikzsetnextfilename{FIG_section_\thesection_convex}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis]
        
        \addplot3 [
            % Aparence
            surf,
            opacity=0.5,
            fill opacity= 1,
            faceted color = white,
            shader=faceted interp,
            % Scope
            data cs = cart, % cart/polar/polarrad
            % Variable
            variable   = u,
            variable y = v,
            domain   = 0:360,
            domain y = -180:0,
        ]
        (
            {cos(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {sin(u)*sin(v)}, 
            {cos(v)}
        );
    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the change in the `nextfilename` but the problem is not to localise each figure, but to find files in a big archive, that is the main `.tex` file as well as its subfiles and several other different projects from which some interact with each other. Having not only all `.tex` files and directories and other related files restricted to use `_` has a big impact in the organisation and "search-ability".

Comment: +1 @DJ9 I do not understand your comment about the "searchability", see also Ulrike's last comment below your question.