# How to disable rendering of certain package content (draft mode)

Tags: compiling, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, rendering, draft

I'm using the `tikz-cd` package for drawing commutative diagrams. Now I want to disable the rendering of the content produced by this package similar to the behaviour when importing the `graphics` package via the draft option. This is for the speed of compiling speed whilst I'm editing the file. Unfortunately the draft option doesn't seem to exist for the `tikz-cd` package, so does anyone have an idea how I can still achieve the above described behaviour?

Comment: The easy solution is to use externalize or standalone.  You could also create a flag (`\newif\ifrender`) and simply test it each time.

Comment: Try `\tikzexternalize`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482560/29873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\newboolean{draftMode}
\setboolean{draftMode}{true}% turn on (true) or off (false)

\usepackage{verbatim}   % \comment and \endcomment
\ifthenelse{\boolean{draftMode}}{%
    \renewenvironment{tikzcd}{\comment}{Draft\endcomment}
}


\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        E \rar & \prod\limits_\alpha D_\alpha \arrow[r, shift left=0.75ex, "c"] \arrow[r, shift right=0.75ex, "d", swap] & \prod\limits_f D_{c(f)}
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Important:** The solution does not work if the commutative diagrams are written this way:

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
    E \rar & \prod\limits_\alpha D_\alpha \arrow[r, shift left=0.75ex, "c"] \arrow[r, shift right=0.75ex, "d", swap] & \prod\limits_f D_{c(f)}
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

So you need a newline before `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: This fails because for centering the tikz images I wrap the environment into `\[ ... \]`

Comment: @Richard - There is `\begin{center} ...\end{center}`, `{\centering ...}`, `\hfil...\par`, and `\noindent\makebox{\textwidth]{...}`.  All of these have fewer side effects than display style math.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for the help!