# Vertical Alignement of Tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex3

Any idea on how i can improve the vertical alignement of the different plots below?

[image]

Made from the following code MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                             % declare the paper format.

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}           %for TikZ graphics
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %for 3dplot functionality

\begin{document}

%harmonics.tex: produces spherical harmonic plots using the 3dplot package
% Author: Jeff Hein
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    %Here's some more examples.
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {1}{black}{0}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 1, M_L = -1
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(3/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)}{black}{-\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 1, M_L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(3)*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{0}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
        %L = 1, M_L = +1
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(3/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 2, M_L = -2
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(15/2)/2*sin(\tdplottheta)^2}{black}{-2*\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 2, M_L = -1
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(15/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{-\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 2, M_L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(5)/2*(3*cos(\tdplottheta)^2 - 1 )}{black}{-\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 2, M_L = 1
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(15/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 2, M_L = +2
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(15/2)/2*sin(\tdplottheta)^2}{black}{2*\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7]
    %L = 3, M_L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(7)/2*(5*cos(\tdplottheta)^3 - 3*cos(\tdplottheta))}{black}{0}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Various spherical harmonics with TikZ}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Adaptations

- I reduced the example to the first three plots.
- Note: You can put all plots into a single `figure` environment
- defined command `\myboundingbox` as follows and used it in every `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\useasboundingbox[draw=yellow] (2.5,0,-1.5) rectangle (0,2.5,3);
```

- option `draw=yellow` is only for testing and can be removed later
- defined `mysphericalsurfaceplot` as tikz style to remove redundancies

#### Tip

If you have many of these computationally expensive plots, it might be beneficial to use externalization (see [How to externalize TikZ pictures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482557/123129)):

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                             % declare the paper format.

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}           %for TikZ graphics
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %for 3dplot functionality

%\usetikzlibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize

\newcommand{\myboundingbox}{%
    \useasboundingbox[draw=yellow] (2.5,0,-1.5) rectangle (0,2.5,3);
}
\tikzset{
    mysphericalsurfaceplot/.style={scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7}
}

\begin{document}

%harmonics.tex: produces spherical harmonic plots using the 3dplot package
% Author: Jeff Hein
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    %Here's some more examples.
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mysphericalsurfaceplot]
        \myboundingbox
        %L = 0
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
        {1}{black}{0}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mysphericalsurfaceplot]
        \myboundingbox
        %L = 1, M_L = -1
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
        {sqrt(3/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)}{black}{-\tdplotphi}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mysphericalsurfaceplot]
        \myboundingbox
        %L = 1, M_L = 0
        \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
        {sqrt(3)*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{0}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
           {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Various spherical harmonics with TikZ}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can name a node that you will use for alignment in each tikzpicture. For example, the node for the x-axis label could be named `x` by inserting `(x)` into the node: `\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east](x){$x$};`

Then add `baseline=(x)` to each tikzpicture.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                             % declare the paper format.
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}           %for TikZ graphics
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} %for 3dplot functionality

\begin{document}

%harmonics.tex: produces spherical harmonic plots using the 3dplot package
% Author: Jeff Hein
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    %Here's some more examples.
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{135}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7, baseline=(x)]
    %L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {1}{black}{0}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east](x){$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7, baseline=(x)]
    %L = 1, M_L = -1
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(3/2)*sin(\tdplottheta)}{black}{-\tdplotphi}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east](x){$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords, fill opacity=.7, baseline=(x)]
    %L = 1, M_L = 0
    \tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
    {sqrt(3)*cos(\tdplottheta)}{black}{0}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[anchor=north east](x){$x$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};}%
       {\draw[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};}%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Various spherical harmonics with TikZ}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```